# How do you modify a CSS style in the code behind file for divs in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

I'm trying to modify a CSS style attribute for a div based on the information I get from a database table in the code behind of my aspx page. The following is essentially what I am trying to do, but I get errors.

Aspx:

```
<div id="testSpace" runat="server">
    Test
</div>
```

Code Behind:

```
testSpace.Style = "display:none;"    
testSpace.Style("display") = "none";
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 172, accepted):

```
testSpace.Style.Add("display", "none");
```

Comment: testSpace.Attributes.Add("style", "display: none;"); would also work.

Comment: No so sure Robert, I think this line will replace existing style with the new one instead of merging both styles.

Comment: Usefully, this replaces an existing style, e.g. you might want to completely change a class attribute.

Answer (score 78):

It's an HtmlGenericControl so not sure what the recommended way to do this is, so you could also do:

```
testSpace.Attributes.Add("style", "text-align: center;");
```

or

```
testSpace.Attributes.Add("class", "centerIt");
```

or

```
testSpace.Attributes["style"] = "text-align: center;";
```

or

```
testSpace.Attributes["class"] = "centerIt";
```

Answer (score 17):

Another way to do it:

```
testSpace.Style.Add("display", "none");
```

or

```
testSpace.Style["background-image"] = "url(images/foo.png)";
```

in vb.net you can do it this way:

```
testSpace.Style.Item("display") = "none"
```

Comment: I had trouble using `testSpace.Style.Item("display") = "none";` on a label control in .NET 4.0.  I got the error `'System.Web.UI.CssStyleCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Item' . . . `.  Is that specific to a particular .NET version?

Comment: i am sorry. the first one was the VB.net approach. i will edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

If you're `new`ing up an element with [initializer syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers#collection-initializers), you can do something like this:

```
var row = new HtmlTableRow
{
  Cells =
  {
    new HtmlTableCell
    {
        InnerText = text,
        Attributes = { ["style"] = "min-width: 35px;" }
    },
  }
};
```

Or if using the `CssStyleCollection` specifically:

```
var row = new HtmlTableRow
{
  Cells =
  {
    new HtmlTableCell
    {
        InnerText = text,
        Style = { ["min-width"] = "35px" }
    },
  }
};
```