# Changing div's style in asp.net

Tags: html, asp.net

is there way to change a `<div>` style arrtibute from the code behind?

for example how do i change the display of`<div ID="id1" style="display:"none">`  to be `diplay:""` in asp.net?

Tnx for the help

Comment: there is nothing called `""` for `display`, it won't reset the display, you need to override by redeclaring the value like `block` `inline-block` etc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you modify style in the code behind file for divs in ASP.net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/657144/how-do-you-modify-style-in-the-code-behind-file-for-divs-in-asp-net)

Comment: Tnx for help, i used block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well to access the div from code-behind, it would need to be `runat="server"` but if it is you just access the style attribute:

```
id1.Attributes["style"] = "display:\"\"";
```

but as Mr. Alien writes in the comment to your question, you probably just want to clear it, or set it to block or something.