# How to Change the HTML button size dynamically

Tags: javascript, c#, html, xaml, windows-phone

I have a web browser in XAML:

```
<phone:WebBrowser x:Name="Browser"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2"
                  Navigating="Browser_Navigating"/>
```

It displays HTML content present in isolated storage so I retrieve the content and store it in a string to display it on `WebBrowser`,

```
Browser.NavigateToString(str);
```

The string contains a button which acts as a link. I want to change the size of this button.I do not know how to access the button present in string which is stored inside Isolated storage. Any idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you modify style in the code behind file for divs in ASP.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657144/how-do-you-modify-style-in-the-code-behind-file-for-divs-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 0):

There are more than just one way to get this done.
It's about string-manipulation.

**Example 1:** 
Search through the HTML-String for the ID or Name of the Button.
If you found it: simply add `style="font-size:99px"` into the Buttons Tag, where the 99 is the size of it. Change it how you like to.

**Example 2:**
If you know that the CSS (Styling) is in the same Website (String) then you can edit or add the `font-size` attribute there.

After you did this, just call your edited String like this:

```
Browser.NavigateToString(EditedString);
```

If you've got questions, ask ;)

Comment: B.Müller thanks for replying..I do not want to change the size of button in HTML-String , I wanted to know if I can change it in c# code using javascript or some other way..Pardon if I am asking wrong question.

Comment: Sorry, i am not familiar with this. The only way i would do it is as described above. You could write an method that automaticly finds/resizes the button if you want something near to a script function.